# Kotlin syntax confusion: fun Foo.bar() = (...)

Tags: java, syntax, kotlin

I'm confused on what the following line of code is supposed to be doing:

```
fun MyContext.req() = request as LaunchRequest
```

`LaunchRequest` is a Java class, and `MyContext` is a Kotlin data class. I've tried looking up examples of Kotlin code that use this syntax, but haven't found anything.

`MyContext` doesn't have a `req()` function, so is this just defining a new function for `MyContext` that returns a variable called "request" of type `LaunchRequest`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it is.  https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. It’s an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions) named `req` defined on the receiver `MyContext`. This technique is used to add new functions to existing classes without the use of inheritance. This concrete example `req` can be invoked on any object of `MyContext`.

   If you have a reference of `MyContext` it may be used as follows:

   ```
   val ctx: MyContext = ...
   val req: LaunchRequest = ctx.req()
   ```
2. The `as` keyword is used to cast the variable `request` to `LaunchRequest`.
3. If the `=` in the function declaration also leads to confusion: it’s called function with **expression body**, which can be used to replace *block bodies* (enclosed in curly brackets) when the function contains a [single expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#single-expression-functions) like given in your code.

Answer (score 1):

These are extension functions of Kotlin which help in improving a class's functionality without actually writing a lot of boilerplate code.The function could be also written as

```
  fun MyContext.req(): LaunchRequest(){
     return (request as LaunchRequest)
  }
```

Another example of Extension function(to animate view)is:

```
fun View.animatePulsing() {
 val animation = AnimatorSet()
 ....
 ....
 animation.duration = 150
 animation.start()
}
```

We can use this as:

```
 txtView.animatePulsing()
```